# Mapbox - Map loads on iOS but not on Android

Tags: android, react-native, mapbox

I am working on a react-native app that was running on iOS using react-native-mapbox-gl/maps. I replaced react-native-mapbox-gl/maps with rnmapbox/maps using maplibre. Now this map loads on iOS but not on Android. This is the code

```
  <MapboxGL.MapView style={editStyles.map} onRegionIsChanging={(features) => handleRegionChange(features)}
      styleURL='mapbox://styles/accessos/ckh0y1uzb03gr19s1rkbjhx2v?optimize=true'
      onDidFinishLoadingMap={() => handleMapLoad()}
      onDidFinishRenderingFrame={() => handleMapLoad()}
      >
      <MapboxGL.BackgroundLayer style={editStyles.mapLayer} id={'Filter Layer'} />
      <TouchableOpacity style={editStyles.recenterContainer} onPress={() => {
          setCoordinates([coordinates[0] + 0.0000001, coordinates[1]]);
          setConfigCoordinates([coordinates[0], coordinates[1]]);
          reverseGeocode(coordinates[0], coordinates[1], apiKey);
          getBounds();
      }}>
          <Image source={require('../assets/recenterbutton.png')} style={editStyles.recenterButton} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <MapboxGL.Camera
          zoomLevel={16}
          centerCoordinate={coordinates}
          animationDuration={0}
          maxBounds={bounds}
        />
      <MapboxGL.ShapeSource id="bounds" shape={polygon}>
          <MapboxGL.FillLayer id="boundsFill" style={boundsStyle} />
          <MapboxGL.LineLayer id="layer1" style={searchStyles.lineLayer} />
        </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>
    <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation coordinate={coordinates} id='p2' >
          <View style={editStyles.currentOuterMarker}>
              <View style={editStyles.currentMarker} />
          </View>
      </MapboxGL.PointAnnotation>
      <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation coordinate={configCoordinates} id='p3' >
          <View style={editStyles.outerMarker}>
              <View style={editStyles.marker} />
          </View>
      </MapboxGL.PointAnnotation>
    </MapboxGL.MapView>
```

and this is the error on the emulator.

[image]

I don't see any errors in the console.

Thank you for any help you can provide.